# Livecode Datagridform - How to load remote Images

Tags: datagrid, livecode

I'am using a datagridform populated with data from mysql.

One field contains an imagepath to a https address on a web server to get thumbnail images.

in my on FillInData handler i have:

if pDataArray["products_image"] is not empty then
set the fileName of image "ProductsImage" of me to pDataArray["products_image"]
end if

Sometimes it works fine and sometimes livecode hangs and has to be restated.

This problem appears if the image is not available or is not loaded quick enough.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Using livecode 7.01. / 7.04 on OS X 10.10

Answer (score 0):

maybe a `wait xx milliseconds` before `end if` cand make sure it does not time out